# Power over Coax (PoC) filter design calculations

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, emc, emi-filtering, passive-filter

I need to design a PoC filter for one of my project. I am referring [this document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla224a/snla224a.pdf?ts=1708644945684&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDS90UB960-Q1&_ticdt=MTcwODY2MTg5M3wwMTg3NDY4MDk2NDgwMDE0MzkxYzRjZGY0YjZiMDUwNmYwMDM0MDY3MDA5Nzh8R0ExLjEuMTE3ODkxMzQ1LjE2ODA1MTUwNDV8bnVsbHxudWxsfEdTMS4xLjE3MDg2NjA5MDkuMjEzLjEuMTcwODY2MTg5My4wLjAuMHxudWxsfEdTMS4xLjE2OTgzODM4NjQuMS4xLjE2OTgzODM5NzEuMC4wLjB8bnVsbA) for the same. Below is the PoC filter given in page in 13. I am using only TI parts. This document is from TI.

[image]

This document does not contain any mathematical calculations of how they arrived the component values.

For example lets us take L1,it's value is 10 uH. Why 10 uH? Why not 1 uH or 100 uH?

How they arrived the spec for FB1, FB2 and FB3?

Can someone please explain the math behind these?

Comment: The inductance value depends on the slowest data rate to be transmitted. Then the FBs are there to ensure that the SRF of the inductor does not screw things up.

Comment: Thank you.May I know how  FBs ensure that the SRF of the inductor does not screw things.How to design inductor from data rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *For example lets us take L1, it's value is 10uH. Why 10uH? Why not 1uH
> or 100uH?*

Data and DC power are superimposed and, what you don't want is the impedance of the applied DC voltage to be so inflexible that data gets badly distorted or highly attenuated. So, you need an inductor. It's called [phantom powering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_power) and, if you know anything about telephones, you'll know that to superimpose audio on top of the DC power you need a DC supply with high compliance.

It's the same with ethernet if you want to transmit power and data together; you need an interface that can combine both without corrupting the data and, without radically reducing the power.

So, if your lowest data rate is (say) 10 kbps, you need to ensure that the inductor that feeds power has an impedance at 5 kHz that is significantly higher that the data's source impedance. If the data impedance is 50 Ω, you want the inductor to have an impedance of 500 Ω (or more) at 5 kHz.

That's 16 mH (give or take)

- If the lowest data rate is 1 Mbps you choose an inductor to be no smaller than 160 μH.
- If the lowest data rate is 10 Mbps you choose an inductor to be no smaller than 16 μH.

These are rules of thumb but, in reality, if the data has long periods of idle then you have to ensure that the idle condition is removed by (typically) scrambling the data. You need to understand your data before making decisions on the inductor.

> *How they arrived the spec for FB1, FB2 and FB3?*

The ferrite beads counteract the problem that all inductors have aka self-resonant frequency. Above the SRF the inductor starts to behave like a capacitor and that will corrupt data quite badly so, you ensure that FBs are added in series with the inductor so that they keep the impedance (looking into the power line) high for a wide range of frequencies.

Comment: May I know ,How ferrite beads counteract the inductor SRF Problem." FBs are added in series with the inductor so that they keep the impedance (looking into the power line) high for a wide range of frequencies." Here impedance of FB matters more than the impedance of inductor.

Comment: @Hari If an inductor is in series with an FB, only one needs to have high impedance. At DC both are near zero ohm and pass the power DC. At (say) 1 GHz the FBs create the high impedance and, at the slowest data rate frequencies the inductor is the dominant impedance.